# For each Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a code in VB6 which i need to convert to VB.NET, in VB6 I had 5 textboxes named t(0),t(1),t(2), t(3) and t(4) for which this code worked:

```
Suma = 0
For i = 1 To 4
Suma = Suma + t(i).Text
Next
 If CDbl(Suma) > Label13.Caption Then
 t(Index).Text = 0
 Suma = 0
 t(Index).SelStart = 0
 t(Index).SelLength = 1
 For i = 1 To 4
 Suma = Suma + t(i).Text
 Next
 End If
 t(0).Text = Format(Label13.Caption - CDbl(Suma), "#,##0.00")
Else
Suma = 0
For i = 0 To 3
Suma = Suma + t(i).Text
Next
 If CDbl(Suma) > Label13.Caption Then
 t(Index).Text = 0
 Suma = 0
 t(Index).SelStart = 0
 t(Index).SelLength = 1
 For i = 0 To 3
 Suma = Suma + t(i).Text
 Next
 End If
 t(4).Text = Format(Label13.Caption - CDbl(Suma), "#,##0.00")
```

Now, in VB.net i have textboxes named: `t0,t1,t2,t3,t4`

How would i loop through these textboxes in VB.net like i did in VB6?

Comment: put them in an array/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this concept :

```
For c As Integer = 0 To 4
    CType(Me.Controls("t" & c.ToString()), TextBox).Text = "t" & c.ToString()
Next
```

In your case, it would be something like this :

```
Suma = 0
For i = 1 To 4
    Suma = Suma + CInt(CType(Me.Controls("t" & i.ToString()), TextBox).Text)
Next

'Rest of your code following the above concept
```